# SQlite Me detecta el 0 como null

Tags: c#, sqlite

Tengo que insertar un registro en tiempo de ejecución donde uno de los parámetros es 0 ;

```
        using (SQLiteConnection conexion = new SQLiteConnection(conectionString))
        {
            //Inserta Investigacion1
            SQLiteCommand investigacion1 = new SQLiteCommand();
            investigacion1.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Investigacion_Partida (idPartida, idInvestigacion, nivel) VALUES (@idPartida,@idInvestigacion,@nivel)";
            investigacion1.Connection = conexion;
            investigacion1.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@idPartida", idPartida));
            investigacion1.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@idInvestigacion", 1));
            investigacion1.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@nivel", 0));
            conexion.Open();
            investigacion1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conexion.Close();
        }
```

El problema es que ese 0 lo detecta como un nulo y es curioso puesto que si pongo la misma instrucción en Query si que introduce el 0 y lo inserta perfectamente.(Si cambio el 0 por un uno por ejemplo también lo inserta bien)

```
insert into Investigacion_Partida values(1,1,0);
```

Esto si funciona y creo que es exactamente lo mismo que quiero decir en c#.

Comment: Tipo: bigint, not null, pero lo que digo yo, un 0 no es un nulo :(

Comment: Estoy intentando implementarlo pero no lo consigo,  new SQLiteParameter("@nivel", SqliteType.Integer), SqliteType.Integer me dice que no esta definido voy a investigar como definirlo

Comment: Prueba con .AddWithValue. Por cierto, no tendrás ningún trigger en esa tabla? (por si falla el insert en otra por ejemplo de históricos..) Si funciona idInvestigacion debería de funcionar nivel también. Añade también el error (si diera alguno).

Comment: he intentador investigacion1.Parameters.AddWithValue(new SQLiteParameter("@nivel",cero)); de varias maneras; int cero =0 pero no lo consigo, fallo en el compilador, no detectar el object value, no hay triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabo de solucionarlo, poniendo;

```
 int cero = 0
 investigacion1.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@nivel",cero));
```

No le paso el valor directamente, esta definido en una variable.
Hay algunas cosas que son incomprensibles... jajaj

Comment: Tiene una explicación... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352260/why-does-the-sqlparameter-name-value-constructor-treat-0-as-null

Comment: Esto probablemente solucionaría el problema también, definiendo el tipo del parámetro: `investigacion1.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(DbType.Int32,"@nivel")); investigacion1.Parameters[2].Value=0;`

Comment: Gracias a los 2 por las molestias, ahora pruebo lo que dices Pikoh.

Comment: saludos @HectorLopez, ¿podrías marcar la respuesta como aceptada por favor? Ayudarrías a mantener la buena salud del sitio, gracias :D